# ASP.NET to Mobile

Tags: ios, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.ios

Right now I am developing a website in visual studio using ASP.NET and C#. Is there any easy way to turn it into an application where iPhone users can get it on the app store. I heard something about Xamarin(monotouch), but I did not really understand exactly what it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Xamarin is a framework that lets you write Apps for iOS and Android using C# and accessing the native API frameworks.  It does not allow you to simply port any .NET app to a mobile platform.

You can use responsive design to allow your ASP.NET site to work with both desktop and mobile browsers.  See http://www.asp.net/mobile

Answer (score 0):

As Jason wrote Monotouch enables you to build native applications. If you would choose a single page application approach you would be able to put the output in PhoneGap to publish it to the AppStore/Google Play.

That requires a bit of different thinking and doing, as you can't rely on the classic model with controllers/views and hard links.

However, it is still possible and I did it already for a project. I have an ASP.NET MVC application with Razor etc. as foundation, so I can easily manage the different "pages", dozens of different script files etc. However, all pages are Parial Views rendered within one single page. The nice thing about is, that this application works in each browser and is testable, too. To get it additionaly in an app container, we wrote a little tool that grabs all the output of that single page and converts it to a static HTML file, copying and referencing all the images, stylesheets and scripts, too.